# The curvature of a circular arc is backwards

Tags: tikz-pgf, angle, tikz-angles

The curvature of the circular arc indicating the angle at ∡OPR is backwards.  The command that I used to draw it is the last line in the code.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);

\draw[-latex,name path=ray_1] (O) -- (10:8);
\coordinate (label_for_ray_r_1) at ($(10:8) +(10:3mm)$);
\node at (label_for_ray_r_1){$r_{1}$};
\draw[-latex,name path=ray_2] (O) -- (50:8);
\coordinate (label_for_ray_r_2) at ($(45:8) +(50:0.3)$);
\node at (label_for_ray_r_2){$r_{2}$};
\draw[-latex,name path=ray_3] (O) -- (75:8);
\coordinate (label_for_ray_r_3) at ($(75:8) +(75:0.3)$);
\node at (label_for_ray_r_3){$r_{3}$};


\coordinate (Q) at (75:6.5);
\draw[fill] (Q) circle (1.5pt);
\coordinate (P) at ($(O)!(Q)!(50:8)$);
\draw[fill,blue] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[name path=path_PQ] (P) -- (Q);

%A right-angle mark is drawn at P.
\coordinate (U) at ($(P)!4mm!-45:(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(Q)$);


\coordinate (A) at ($(O)!(Q)!(10:8)$);
\draw[fill] (A) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[name path=path_AQ] (A) -- (Q);

\coordinate (B) at ($(O)!(P)!(10:8)$);
\draw[fill] (B) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (B) -- (P);

\coordinate (R) at ($(A)!(P)!(Q)$);
\draw[fill,blue] (R) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (P) -- (R);

%The label for O is typeset.
\coordinate (label_O_below_left) at ($(O)!-7mm!(10:8)$);
\coordinate (label_O_below) at ($(O)!-7mm!(75:8)$);
\coordinate (label_O) at ($(label_O_below_left)!0.5!(label_O_below)$);
\node[blue] at ($(O)!3mm!(label_O)$){$O$};

%The label for Q is typeset.
\coordinate (label_Q_left) at ($(Q)!-7mm!(P)$);
\coordinate (label_Q_right) at ($(Q)!-7mm!(A)$);
\coordinate (label_Q) at ($(label_Q_left)!0.5!(label_Q_right)$);
\node[blue] at ($(Q)!3mm!(label_Q)$){$Q$};

%The label for P is typeset.
\coordinate (label_P_above_right) at ($(P)!15mm!(50:8)$);
\coordinate (label_P_below) at ($(P)!15mm!(B)$);
\coordinate (label_P) at ($(label_P_above_right)!0.5!(label_P_below)$);
\node[blue] at ($(P)!3mm!(label_P)$){$P$};

%The label for R is typeset.
\coordinate (label_R) at ($(R)!-4mm!(P)$);
\node[blue] at (label_R){$R$};

%The labels for A and B are typeset.
\coordinate (label_A) at ($(A)!-3mm!(Q)$);
\node[blue] at (label_A){$A$};
\coordinate (label_B) at ($(B)!-3mm!(P)$);
\node[blue] at (label_B){$B$};


%A right-angle mark is drawn at A.
\coordinate (U_2) at ($(A)!4mm!-45:(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U_2) -- ($(A)!(U_2)!(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U_2) -- ($(A)!(U_2)!(Q)$);


%A right-angle mark is drawn at B.
\coordinate (U_3) at ($(B)!4mm!-45:(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U_3) -- ($(B)!(U_3)!(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U_3) -- ($(B)!(U_3)!(P)$);

%A right-angle mark is drawn at R.
\coordinate (U_4) at ($(R)!4mm!45:(P)$);
\draw[dashed] (U_4) -- ($(R)!(U_4)!(Q)$);
\draw[dashed] (U_4) -- ($(R)!(U_4)!(P)$);


%The angle at O with a measure of x is drawn.
\draw[draw=blue] (O) ++(10:5mm) arc (10:50:5mm);
\coordinate (label_for_x) at (30:0.75);
\node[font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_x){$x$};

%The angle at O with a measure of y is drawn.
\draw[draw=blue] (O) ++(50:7.5mm) arc (50:75:7.5mm);
\coordinate (label_for_y) at (62.5:0.9);
\node[font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_y){$y$};


%An angle at Q  with measure x is drawn.
\draw[draw=blue] let \p1=($(A)-(Q)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(P)-(Q)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in ($(Q)!0.5cm!(A)$) arc (\n1:\n2:0.5);

%The label x for the measure of the angle at Q is typeset.
\coordinate (midpoint_of_PR) at ($(P)!0.5!(R)$);
\coordinate (label_for_x_at_Q) at ($(Q)!0.75cm!(midpoint_of_PR)$);
\node[font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_x_at_Q){$x$};

%An angle at P with measure x is drawn.
\draw[draw=blue] let \p1=($(P)-(O)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(P)-(R)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in ($(P)!0.5cm!(R)$) arc (\n1:\n2:0.5);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is not exactly minimal, is it?

Comment: @cfr  No.  It looks nice, though.

Comment: `\draw[draw=blue,xscale=-1] 
  let \p1=($(P)-(O)$), 
  \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, 
  \p2=($(P)-(R)$), 
  \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} 
  in 
  ($(P)!0.5cm!(O)$) arc (\n1:\n2:0.5);`

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina  It seems that you only added `xscale=-1` to this command.  I have not seen this option for the `\draw` command.  What does it instruct `TikZ` to do?

Comment: @user74973 it's a reflection through the y-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angles, calculated by `atan`, are not unambiguous. In the problematic case you get the other angles of the line parts outside P. Adding 180° and moving the starting point to PO helps:

```
\draw[draw=blue]
  let \p1=($(P)-(O)$),
      \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)+180},
      \p2=($(P)-(R)$),
      \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)+180}
  in
  ($(P)!0.5cm!(O)$) arc (\n1:\n2:0.5);
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Are you saying that with `atan(\y1/\x1)` and `atan(\y2/\x2)`, the angles were in Quadrant I?

Comment: @user74973 Yes. `\n1` is 49.99329° and `\n2` is 9.75604° in the code of the question.

Comment: I have a question about using `arc`.  Why does `($(P)!0.5cm!(R)$) arc (50:10:0.5)` draw the arc the "wrong way" about `P`?  The endpoints of the arc are in the "right places."

Comment: @user74973 The arc has the correct form for an arc in the first quadrant of its center point, because its start and end angles are in the first quadrant.

Comment: I guess that I do not know how `TikZ` determines what the center point is in the command `($(P)!0.5cm!(R)$) arc (50:10:0.5)`.  Please tell me.

Comment: @user74973 The center point is indirectly determined in such a way, that the current point `($(P)!0.5cm!(R)$)` is the starting point of the arc. The center point is reached by starting at the current point and going 0.5 cm with angle 50° in the reverse direction, that makes an angle of 50° + 180° = 230°. For illustration, the circle of the arc with center point: `\draw[red] ($(P)!0.5cm!(R) + (50+180:0.5cm)$) circle[radius=1pt] circle[radius=0.5cm];`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve the ambiguity with `atan` is to reflect using `xscale=-1` and moving the strating point to `($(P)!0.5cm!(O)$)`:

```
\draw[draw=blue,xscale=-1] 
  let \p1=($(P)-(O)$), 
  \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, 
  \p2=($(P)-(R)$), 
  \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} 
  in 
  ($(P)!0.5cm!(O)$) arc (\n1:\n2:0.5);
```

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);

\draw[-latex,name path=ray_1] (O) -- (10:8);
\coordinate (label_for_ray_r_1) at ($(10:8) +(10:3mm)$);
\node at (label_for_ray_r_1){$r_{1}$};
\draw[-latex,name path=ray_2] (O) -- (50:8);
\coordinate (label_for_ray_r_2) at ($(45:8) +(50:0.3)$);
\node at (label_for_ray_r_2){$r_{2}$};
\draw[-latex,name path=ray_3] (O) -- (75:8);
\coordinate (label_for_ray_r_3) at ($(75:8) +(75:0.3)$);
\node at (label_for_ray_r_3){$r_{3}$};


\coordinate (Q) at (75:6.5);
\draw[fill] (Q) circle (1.5pt);
\coordinate (P) at ($(O)!(Q)!(50:8)$);
\draw[fill,blue] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[name path=path_PQ] (P) -- (Q);

%A right-angle mark is drawn at P.
\coordinate (U) at ($(P)!4mm!-45:(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(Q)$);


\coordinate (A) at ($(O)!(Q)!(10:8)$);
\draw[fill] (A) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[name path=path_AQ] (A) -- (Q);

\coordinate (B) at ($(O)!(P)!(10:8)$);
\draw[fill] (B) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (B) -- (P);

\coordinate (R) at ($(A)!(P)!(Q)$);
\draw[fill,blue] (R) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (P) -- (R);

%The label for O is typeset.
\coordinate (label_O_below_left) at ($(O)!-7mm!(10:8)$);
\coordinate (label_O_below) at ($(O)!-7mm!(75:8)$);
\coordinate (label_O) at ($(label_O_below_left)!0.5!(label_O_below)$);
\node[blue] at ($(O)!3mm!(label_O)$){$O$};

%The label for Q is typeset.
\coordinate (label_Q_left) at ($(Q)!-7mm!(P)$);
\coordinate (label_Q_right) at ($(Q)!-7mm!(A)$);
\coordinate (label_Q) at ($(label_Q_left)!0.5!(label_Q_right)$);
\node[blue] at ($(Q)!3mm!(label_Q)$){$Q$};

%The label for P is typeset.
\coordinate (label_P_above_right) at ($(P)!15mm!(50:8)$);
\coordinate (label_P_below) at ($(P)!15mm!(B)$);
\coordinate (label_P) at ($(label_P_above_right)!0.5!(label_P_below)$);
\node[blue] at ($(P)!3mm!(label_P)$){$P$};

%The label for R is typeset.
\coordinate (label_R) at ($(R)!-4mm!(P)$);
\node[blue] at (label_R){$R$};

%The labels for A and B are typeset.
\coordinate (label_A) at ($(A)!-3mm!(Q)$);
\node[blue] at (label_A){$A$};
\coordinate (label_B) at ($(B)!-3mm!(P)$);
\node[blue] at (label_B){$B$};


%A right-angle mark is drawn at A.
\coordinate (U_2) at ($(A)!4mm!-45:(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U_2) -- ($(A)!(U_2)!(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U_2) -- ($(A)!(U_2)!(Q)$);


%A right-angle mark is drawn at B.
\coordinate (U_3) at ($(B)!4mm!-45:(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U_3) -- ($(B)!(U_3)!(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U_3) -- ($(B)!(U_3)!(P)$);

%A right-angle mark is drawn at R.
\coordinate (U_4) at ($(R)!4mm!45:(P)$);
\draw[dashed] (U_4) -- ($(R)!(U_4)!(Q)$);
\draw[dashed] (U_4) -- ($(R)!(U_4)!(P)$);


%The angle at O with a measure of x is drawn.
\draw[draw=blue] (O) ++(10:5mm) arc (10:50:5mm);
\coordinate (label_for_x) at (30:0.75);
\node[font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_x){$x$};

%The angle at O with a measure of y is drawn.
\draw[draw=blue] (O) ++(50:7.5mm) arc (50:75:7.5mm);
\coordinate (label_for_y) at (62.5:0.9);
\node[font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_y){$y$};


%An angle at Q  with measure x is drawn.
\draw[draw=blue] let \p1=($(A)-(Q)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(P)-(Q)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in ($(Q)!0.5cm!(A)$) arc (\n1:\n2:0.5);

%The label x for the measure of the angle at Q is typeset.
\coordinate (midpoint_of_PR) at ($(P)!0.5!(R)$);
\coordinate (label_for_x_at_Q) at ($(Q)!0.75cm!(midpoint_of_PR)$);
\node[font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_x_at_Q){$x$};

%An angle at P with measure x is drawn.
\draw[draw=blue,xscale=-1] 
  let \p1=($(P)-(O)$), 
  \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, 
  \p2=($(P)-(R)$), 
  \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} 
  in 
  ($(P)!0.5cm!(O)$) arc (\n1:\n2:0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you are loading the `angles` library but not using it. Let the library do the work.  Use `quotes` library too if you want to label the angle.

```
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
%An angle at Q  with measure x is drawn.
\path pic[draw=blue,angle radius=5mm,"$\scriptstyle{x}$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = A--Q--P};      

%An angle at P with measure x is drawn.  

\path pic[draw=blue,angle radius=5mm,angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = R--P--O};
```

Your code can be reduced drastically by this method. I have left comments in your code below.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,quotes,positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);

\draw[-latex,name path=ray_1] (O) -- (10:8);
\coordinate (label_for_ray_r_1) at ($(10:8) +(10:3mm)$);
\node at (label_for_ray_r_1){$r_{1}$};
\draw[-latex,name path=ray_2] (O) -- (50:8);
\coordinate (label_for_ray_r_2) at ($(45:8) +(50:0.3)$);
\node at (label_for_ray_r_2){$r_{2}$};
\draw[-latex,name path=ray_3] (O) -- (75:8);
\coordinate (label_for_ray_r_3) at ($(75:8) +(75:0.3)$);
\node at (label_for_ray_r_3){$r_{3}$};


\coordinate (Q) at (75:6.5);
\draw[fill] (Q) circle (1.5pt);
\coordinate (P) at ($(O)!(Q)!(50:8)$);
\draw[fill,blue] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[name path=path_PQ] (P) -- (Q);

%A right-angle mark is drawn at P.
\coordinate (U) at ($(P)!4mm!-45:(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(Q)$);


\coordinate (A) at ($(O)!(Q)!(10:8)$);
\draw[fill] (A) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[name path=path_AQ] (A) -- (Q);

\coordinate (B) at ($(O)!(P)!(10:8)$);
\draw[fill] (B) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (B) -- (P);

\coordinate (R) at ($(A)!(P)!(Q)$);
\draw[fill,blue] (R) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (P) -- (R);

%The label for O is typeset.
\coordinate (label_O_below_left) at ($(O)!-7mm!(10:8)$);
\coordinate (label_O_below) at ($(O)!-7mm!(75:8)$);
\coordinate (label_O) at ($(label_O_below_left)!0.5!(label_O_below)$);
\node[blue] at ($(O)!3mm!(label_O)$){$O$};

%The label for Q is typeset.
\coordinate (label_Q_left) at ($(Q)!-7mm!(P)$);
\coordinate (label_Q_right) at ($(Q)!-7mm!(A)$);
\coordinate (label_Q) at ($(label_Q_left)!0.5!(label_Q_right)$);
\node[blue] at ($(Q)!3mm!(label_Q)$){$Q$};

%The label for P is typeset.
\coordinate (label_P_above_right) at ($(P)!15mm!(50:8)$);
\coordinate (label_P_below) at ($(P)!15mm!(B)$);
\coordinate (label_P) at ($(label_P_above_right)!0.5!(label_P_below)$);
\node[blue] at ($(P)!3mm!(label_P)$){$P$};

%The label for R is typeset.
\coordinate (label_R) at ($(R)!-4mm!(P)$);
\node[blue] at (label_R){$R$};

%The labels for A and B are typeset.
\coordinate (label_A) at ($(A)!-3mm!(Q)$);
\node[blue] at (label_A){$A$};
\coordinate (label_B) at ($(B)!-3mm!(P)$);
\node[blue] at (label_B){$B$};


%A right-angle mark is drawn at A.
\coordinate (U_2) at ($(A)!4mm!-45:(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U_2) -- ($(A)!(U_2)!(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U_2) -- ($(A)!(U_2)!(Q)$);


%A right-angle mark is drawn at B.
\coordinate (U_3) at ($(B)!4mm!-45:(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U_3) -- ($(B)!(U_3)!(O)$);
\draw[dashed] (U_3) -- ($(B)!(U_3)!(P)$);

%A right-angle mark is drawn at R.
\coordinate (U_4) at ($(R)!4mm!45:(P)$);
\draw[dashed] (U_4) -- ($(R)!(U_4)!(Q)$);
\draw[dashed] (U_4) -- ($(R)!(U_4)!(P)$);


%The angle at O with a measure of x is drawn.
\draw[draw=blue] (O) ++(10:5mm) arc (10:50:5mm);
\coordinate (label_for_x) at (30:0.75);
\node[font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_x){$x$};

%The angle at O with a measure of y is drawn.
\draw[draw=blue] (O) ++(50:7.5mm) arc (50:75:7.5mm);
\coordinate (label_for_y) at (62.5:0.9);
\node[font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_y){$y$};


%An angle at Q  with measure x is drawn.
%\draw[draw=blue] let \p1=($(A)-(Q)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(P)-(Q)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in ($(Q)!0.5cm!(A)$) arc (\n1:\n2:0.5);
\path pic[draw=blue,angle radius=5mm,"$\scriptstyle{x}$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = A--Q--P};

%The label x for the measure of the angle at Q is typeset.  Not needed with angles library
%\coordinate (midpoint_of_PR) at ($(P)!0.5!(R)$);
%\coordinate (label_for_x_at_Q) at ($(Q)!0.75cm!(midpoint_of_PR)$);
%\node[font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_x_at_Q){$x$};

%An angle at P with measure x is drawn.
%\draw[draw=blue] let \p1=($(P)-(O)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(P)-(R)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in ($(P)!0.5cm!(R)$) arc (\n1:\n2:0.5);

\path pic[draw=blue,angle radius=5mm,angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = R--P--O};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I should have omitted the `angles` package.  I was using this as an example to use the `let - in` syntax.

Comment: How TikZ determines that `P` is the center point in the command `($(P)!0.5cm!(R)$) arc (50:10:0.5)`?  I am also trying to get familiar with the `arc` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The last line should read:

```
\draw[draw=blue] let \p1=($(P)-(O)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(P)-(R)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in ($(P)!0.5cm!(R)$) arc (\n2:\n1:-.5);
```

and now this gives you:

[image]

Comment: The only change that you have is `-0.5` for the radius.  Why does that work?  Why does `TikZ` draw it the wrong way with my command using `0.5` for the radius?

Comment: @user74973 Using `-.5` will have the effect of reflecting the radius, but then it will start drawing from PR so we reverse the order.